# Doctrine 2 join two tables with third using four table

Tags: php, sql, join, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm confused, and spend 2 days for find answer for this question and nothing.
I am already have 5 tables

- Language -> id, iso_code
- I18n_Entity -> id
- I18n_String -> id, i18n_entity_id, language_id, text
- Product -> id, i18n_entity_id(unique)
- Category -> id, i18n_entity_id(unique)

I need to do 2 methods

**getProductByName(Language $language, $name);**

So, normal PostgreSQL query for this purpose is:

```
SELECT p.*, i18s.text
FROM product as p
INNER JOIN I18n_String AS i18s ON i18s.i18n_entity_id = p.i18n_entity_id AND i18s.language_id = :language_id
WHERE i18s.text = :name
```

**getCategoryByName(Language $language, $name);**

```
SELECT c.*, i18s.text
FROM category as c
INNER JOIN I18n_String AS i18s ON i18s.i18n_entity_id = c.i18n_entity_id AND i18s.language_id = :language_id
WHERE i18s.text = :name
```

I know about of join can be through INNER JOIN i18n_Entity as i18e ON i18e.id = p.i18n_entity_id but this is unnecessary.

The question is: can it be done with doctrine, and if yes, how to do right annotation and dql?

**product.php**

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="product_i18n_entity_id_unique", columns={"i18n_entity_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="product_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\I18nEntity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\I18nEntity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="i18n_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $i18nEntity;
    ...
```

i18nEntityId.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * I18nEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="i18n_entity", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="i18n_entity_status_index", columns={"status"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class I18nEntity {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="i18n_entity_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;
    ...
```

i18nString.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * I18nString
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="i18n_string", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="i18n_string_language_id_entity_id_uniq", columns={"language_id", "i18n_entity_id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="i18n_string_language_id_idx", columns={"language_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="i18n_string_entity_id_idx", columns={"i18n_entity_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class I18nString {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="i18n_string_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\I18nEntity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\I18nEntity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="i18n_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $i18nEntity;
    ...
```

Comment: Doctrine is designed to abstract all the SQL generation from you. If you correctly configure the entity annotations then you will not even need to create this query in DQL

Comment: @AlexP Hi, i don't understand how to write right annotation for this situation, can any one help ?